# Codeigniter with ajax: success function not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with success function in my  $.ajax function
in javascript file:

```
$("#country select").change(function () { 
            var country_value = $(this).val(); 
            $.ajax({
                url:base_url + "Search_controller/testing_controller", 
                method: 'post',
                data: {country_val: country_value },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('done : ' + data);  
                },
                   error: function (reponse) {
                console.log('Problem with ajax');
                }

            });
```

**my Controller function**

```
   <?php 

class Search_controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){

    }


    public function testing_controller(){
        $data ="statessssssss";
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

  }
?>
```

**

> The Problem is the codes do nothing, i don't know what the problem 
>   Always return to me in Browser log 'Problem with ajax'

**

Comment: in your $ajax function: baseurl seems to be undefined, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471945/how-can-you-use-php-in-a-javascript-function. Does your browser's console return any error ? (press F12 to show the console)

Comment: baseurl  is defined

Comment: Thanks, but your solution not working !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I find the solution is because of CSRF security**

```
$("#country select").change(function () { 
             var country_value= $(this).val(); 
             var data = { /* params  */
                    "country": country_value,
                     "state": '001'
                };
              data[csfr_token_name] = $.cookie(csfr_cookie_name);
            $.ajax({
                url:base_url + "Search_controller/testing_controller", 
                method: 'post',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('done : ' + data);  
                },
                   error: function (reponse) {
                console.log('Problem with ajax');
                }

            });
```

> This Code Working

Answer (score 1):

`base_url()` is a Codeigniter function (**php**), in your $ajax function you use the **javascript** variable base_url, which is not defined.

in order to get the php base_url() into your $ajax function you need to echo out the php function, changing to this line:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>Search_controller/testing_controller",
```

Comment: is a javascript file not php file

Comment: base_url is defined because i testing after $.ajax  >> console.log(country_value  + ' ' + base_url); and working done , the problem is the ajax with controller

Comment: I tried to explain: base_url is set in Codeigniter, right?, now you are trying to adress the value of base_url in javascript. but that doesn't work, you need to echo it out. I personally prefer just to use `url:"/Search_controller/testing_controller"` but wanted to explain, what you have to do when using base_url in javascript

Comment: i change the url, same problem not reponse ,just console me "Problem with ajax " !!!

Comment: check naming convention: is it **S**earch_controller.php in your controller folder? maybe edit your question adding the controller code?

Comment: yes of course it's "Search_controller.php" also name of Class "Search_controller"

Answer (score 1):

Change your URL as follows

```
url:"<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/Search_controller/testing_controller",
```

I tested your code and its working file.

Comment: if you want index.php included you use site_url(): https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=base_url#site_url

Comment: i change the url, same problem not reponse ,just console me "Problem with ajax " !!!